# Как узнать размер полученного fetch ответа?

Tags: ajax, fetch, асинхронность, xhr

Как узнать размер полученных данных от асинхронного запроса ? Думал что это на вкладке `Fetch/XHR` Можно посмотреть, но оказалось, что `Content-Length: 2280841` - это не про то.

Comment: Content-Length это как раз про то, размер указан в байтах: 2280841 b = 2,3MB

Comment: Как вы определили, что «это не про то»?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773396/whats-the-content-length-field-in-http-header/2773412#2773412

Comment: Из указанной ссылки написано как раз то, что это то, что нужно